# Getting campaign ID with timestamp on app install

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api, facebook-analytics

I'm running a Facebook App Install campaign, but can't install Facebook Analytics SDK due to business constraints. The app event API (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/app-event-api) allows me to post an install event, but only gives true/false as response.
{
  "success": true
}

Is there a way to get campaign ID & timestamp of ad click as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the campaign ID from the API response. However, you can use Facebook Analytics without using the Facebook SDK. You can log events by manually calling the API (which it looks like you're already doing), or through a [Mobile Measurement Partner (MMP)](https://www.facebook.com/help/analytics/615318361942305). As long as the logged event is associated with an advertiser ID or mobile cookie, the Facebook servers will attempt to match it to a user. If the matched user saw an ad in your campaign, then the install event will be associated with a campaign ID.

You can use Facebook Analytics to view information about users that installed your app from your campaign. See [this article](https://www.facebook.com/help/analytics/1682709818695091). That article focuses on using install sources in filters, but they can also be used in other analytics tools, such as breakdown tables.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So what you're saying is I can use the App Event API to log events to Facebook Analytics, which should then reflect in the business manager interface, and can also be retrieved by Reporting API. The problem with that approach is to get the timestamp, as I still will not know if the user installed after clicking on my ad directly, or went through a Google ad before installation. I'm using last click attribution model.

Comment: As far as I know, there's no way to get the timestamp that a specific user saw your ad. I'm more familiar with Facebook Analytics than the Reporting API, though, so maybe it's possible through the Reporting API.